# React: Dynamically created state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to run the code below, but I got an `undefined` from the `console.log` statement.  Any thoughts?

```
this.setState({ [show]: true })
console.log("this.state.show: " , this.state.show);
```

Comment: what is the value of `show` ? this will work if you have `var show = "show"` somewhere

Comment: or `this.state[show]`, which won't work either because `setState` is not synchronous

Comment: `setState()` is asynchronous

Comment: @Taki tried it, still undefined.

Comment: So you can't add any new key/value pairs to state programmatically?

Comment: @KennyLogin Yes, you can add new key/value pairs all you want. You just have to be careful about how you access them afterwards. See the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

In your code you don't set state exactly for show.
Example:

```
const show = 'light';
this.setState({[show]: false}) // you set state for 'light'(this.state.light: false)
```

If you don't set variable show before, you should use:

```
this.setState({ show: true })
```

And if you need to get state right after setting:

```
this.setState({ show: true }, () => console.log("this.state.show: " , this.state.show);)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to check if state did update the best way to do that is simply to check for it inside the `render()` function, because the component is always re-rendered when you update the state. This would probably look like this (I have added a ternary operation as an example of how you can show and hide your component):

```
render(){
  console.log(this.state.show);
  return this.state.show ? <MyComponent /> : null;
}
```

But if you really want to check if the state changed just after using the `setState` function, for example inside another function (and not `render()`), you will need to call `console.log` inside a callback. This is because state takes some time to update and therefore synchronous code would fail. `setState` takes callback functions as a second parameter. So, you can just re-write like this:

```
this.setState({ show: true }, () => console.log("this.state.show: " , this.state.show));
```

Hope that helped...

Comment: Thank you all.  They key is understanding that state is asynchronous and access to new var has to be in a callback.